# SVG path node animation

Tags: svg, path, jquery-animate

I have a svg line chart that I'm trying to mimic the ability to make a selection in it. I already have the path node for the selection, but I'd like to make its width be 0 and when the user clicks over it that the width would scale to the width the user moved along x.

```
<path fill="#D8F2FC" d="M 497.5 1 L 497.5 274 699.5 274 699.5 1"></path>
```

I'd like to stick with javascript as when I use jQuery's mousedown it interferes with the click events that I have set for the parent svg element.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to drag a selection or to just click and it selects a predefined area?

Comment: Hi Kevin,

I want them to be able to mouse down over it and be able to change it's width to the max of 699.5 or 700. Basically, as if they were selecting and highlighting that area of the parent chart. No dragging the selection.

Comment: You can use D3.js to interpolate between the initial path and the target path. I wrote my own JS a while back which can only interpolate between paths because D3 is a pretty big library. I assume you know how to get the click coordinates? Also if you have a line chart already, create a fiddle and I quickly edit the selection JS into it.

Comment: Hi Kevin,

Here is the jsfiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=1I3DGl1GNR.

Comment: I saved to jsfiddle with the udpated URL, http://jsfiddle.net/kirdua/tf2tw4jg/

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to reach, but this is what i got so far.
http://jsfiddle.net/tf2tw4jg/2/

Comment: Hi Kevin,

I think what you have is perfect for what I need. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Hi Kevin,

Hi Kevin,

When I integrated it into my HTML, bigT is coming back as undefined. 

if(typeof path === 'undefined') path = new bigT("#selection", "", {duration:500});

Thanks

Comment: You need to embed this script
https://s3.amazonaws.com/finely/resources/bigT.js

Also if you need any other functionality you should consider another library because I wrote this myself and it only supports basic path tweening.